# Angular 8 edge case: Weird value on ActivatedRoute#data (resolve on parent, data on child => child data gets overwritten)

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-router

I stumbled upon this problem when implementing a simple breadcrumb component.

The idea was to attach `breadcrumb` data on the route's `data` property. And for static values, that worked fine:

```
const routes: Route[] = [
  // ...
  { path: 'outer', data: { breadcrumb: 'outer' }, component: OuterComponent, children: [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', data: { breadcrumb: 'inner' }, component: InnerComponent }
  ] }
  // ...
];
```

This gives me `'outer'` and `'inner'` for the corresponding `ActivatedRoute`s.

For dynamic values, a resolver service seemed like a good solution. And that worked as well, if not for one (weird?) edge case:

```
const routes: Route[] = [
  // ...
  { path: 'outer', resolve: { breadcrumb: OuterResolverService }, component: OuterComponent, children: [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', data: { breadcrumb: 'inner' }, component: InnerComponent }
  ] },
  // ...
];
```

This gives me `'outer'` and `'outer'` (again) for the corresponding `ActivatedRoute`s. This surprised me.

> Note: It does work as expected when the inner component has any path but `''`. `pathMatch: 'full'` doesn't seem to be an influencing factor. I found the following configuration as a working workaround:
>
> ```
> { path: 'outer', resolve: { breadcrumb: 'outer' }, component: OuterComponent, children: [
>   { path: 'inner', data: { breadcrumb: 'inner' }, component: InnerComponent },
>   { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'inner' }
> ]}
> ```

Still, it left me wondering:

- Am I misunderstanding how the `data`/`resolve` mechanism works? (It seems to me from the official documentation that this should be an expected use case, but apparently it doesn't work as I think it should.)
- Is this behavior expected?
- Or is this a bug in Angular 8?

For reference, a stackblitz demonstrating the issue: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odqphj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular offers 2 route params inheritance modes, the default is `emptyOnly` which means that only empty paths inherit their parent params (params include data and resolved data). (the other mode is `always` which means children always inherit parent params, which doesn't help you here)

In this case, you have an empty child path so it is inheriting it's parent params, however, normally, the child data SHOULD take precedence over inherited data if they have a matching key, like it does in your static data case.

BUT, the thing is that resolved data ALWAYS overwrites static data, whether inherited or not (if you had static data and resolved data with the same key on the same route for whatever reason, the static would be overwritten), so the resolved data is overwriting the child data in the resolved parent data case, but not in the static case. Or if you had resolvers at both levels, the child's resolved data would take precedence.

So this isn't a "bug" but it's a quirky / weird behavior. Maybe worth raising with angular, as the order of precedence seems to be: child resolved data, parent resolved data, child data, parent data... when it should be (to me): child resolved data, child data, parent resolved data, parent data. Though I could see arguments either way as the child is technically inheriting the parents resolved data which should be expected to overwrite any static data.

The work around works because your child path technically isn't an empty path. You're just tricking the router into not letting the child inherit.

A slightly different work around available to you is to just use different keywords and have your interested bread crumb component check for both like so:

```
  { 
    path: 'not-working', 
    component: OuterComponent, 
    resolve: { resolvedBreadcrumb: OuterResolverService }, 
    children: [
      { 
        path: '', 
        pathMatch: 'full', 
        component: InnerComponent, 
        data: { breadcrumb: 'inner' }
      }
    ]
  },
```

and:

```
const crumb = route.snapshot.data['breadcrumb'] || route.snapshot.data['resolvedBreadcrumb'];
```

which works as demonstrated here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmw6x1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts